# Int values not reading in from file

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

So I am trying to read values in from a txt file and add them to an ArrayList. I use the following code but immediately after using it the ArrayList is still empty when I use System.out.print(list). Are there any easy to spot mistakes?

```
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner in = null;
    try{
        String fname = "p01-runs.txt";
        in = new Scanner(new File(fname));
    }catch (FileNotFoundException pExcept){
        System.out.println("Sorry, the File you tried to open does not exist. Ending program.");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    while (in.hasNextInt())
    {
        int x = in.nextInt();
        list.add(x);
    }
```

edit: input file is just a txt file with integer values as follows:
2 8 3

2 9

8

6

3 4 6 1 9

Comment: Most likely the file is empty.

Comment: It is not empty, which is the cause for confusion. The file contains a series of integers.

Comment: Apply a counter in while loop to count iterations and also check format of your input file.

Comment: Are you sure your integers in your file are not separated by any other characters but spaces? If they are hyphenated or separated with commas in.nextInt() will return false.

Comment: What is the separator between Int value in the file?

Comment: could you post your input data?Your code works in my system.

Comment: Edited input file into original post.

Comment: Make sure you have only int in the file. Even a colon(:) at the start will give you an empty list...since in.hasNextInt() will be false.

Comment: Also print x and check it has the values.

Comment: The code should work, but make sure you are reading the right input file! Since your code is not throwing an exception about the file, it is finding it and reading it but it might be some empty file, and you might be editing another file somewhere in your file system accidentally!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A call to `hashNextInt()` can return `false` for a number of reasons, including:

- there is no more input, or
- the next token on the input stream is not a valid integer.

These could be due to an empty input file, or to a mismatch between the file's format and the way you are trying to read it.

In your example, it is also possible that some `IOException` apart from `FileNotFoundException` is being thrown.

---

**UPDATE** - The problem is something that you are not telling / showing us.  Consider this ... using your code and your input file.

```
[stephen@blackbox tmp]$ cat Test.java 
import java.util.*;                                                                                                                                           
import java.io.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner in = null;
        try{
            String fname = "test.txt";
            in = new Scanner(new File(fname));
        }catch (FileNotFoundException pExcept){
            System.out.println("Sorry, the File you tried to open does not exist. Ending program.");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        while (in.hasNextInt())
            {
                int x = in.nextInt();
                list.add(x);
            }
        System.out.println("Read " + list.size() + " numbers");
    }
}
[stephen@blackbox tmp]$ cat test.txt 
2 8 3

2 9

8

6

3 4 6 1 9
[stephen@blackbox tmp]$ javac Test.java 
[stephen@blackbox tmp]$ java Test 
Read 12 numbers
[stephen@blackbox tmp]$
```

Comment: I am using a txt file with integers in it that was provided with the instruction for the code I am writing by my professor.

Comment: Not withstanding what you are saying, the `Scanner.hasNextInt()` method behaves as I have described.  Show us the file.

Comment: should I upload the file itself? I edited in the contents of the file to the original post.

Comment: No.  You need to create and upload an MVCE.  We have attempted to create one using the file and the code that you provided, and we cannot reproduce your problem.  Something you are doing is different to what you have shown us.

Comment: Oh wow I'm sorry to waste your time here. As I was looking back through I realized I had accidentally put the output files name where I needed to put the input file. Thank you for your help though!